# Just did system update and forgot I had TWRP and root and now the updates changes havent taken affect!

Tags: updates, nexus-7

Help! I have just installed the Android 4.3 update on my Nexus 7 which is rooted with a vanilla kernel with TWRP installed. It rebooted after the update and it booted straight into TWRP so I rebooted again and then it booted into Android as normal but the OS is still on 4.2.2 and not 4.3. I have tried going into About This Tablet then pressing Update and its saying its not on the latest version...
Help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to 4.3 may be unrooting and flashing the stock recovery image.

I used the Nexus Root Toolkit 1.6.4 to install 4.3 on a Galaxy Nexus having some minor problems. I would suggest waiting for NRT 1.6.6 which will have full support for 4.3